# Convert Excel workbook to CSV with user-provided filenames

Tags: vbscript

First, I need to delete the top 4 rows from the sheet either before or after the conversion. There currently isn't anything in this script that will delete rows from the Excel file or from the CSV file that it creates.

Second, I'd prefer to pass the source and destination in this script rather then passing them later. Currently this script requires a command line to pass the source and destination it looks something like this.

```
C:\exceltocsv "source.xls" "destination.csv"
```

Instead of requiring `source.xls` and `destination.csv` to be provided as commandline arguments I'd rather have them resolved in the VBScript itself. Is this possible?

```
if WScript.Arguments.Count < 2 Then
    WScript.Echo "Error! Please specify the source path and the destination. Usage: XlsToCsv SourcePath.xls Destination.csv"
    Wscript.Quit
End If
Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim oBook
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
oBook.SaveAs WScript.Arguments.Item(1), 6
oBook.Worksheets(2).Activate
oBook.Close False
oExcel.Quit
WScript.Echo "Done"
```

Comment: What's not working about it?  Please don't make us guess.

Comment: There is a "first" and a "second" that should help you not have to guess.

Comment: You need to be more specific.  For instance, you say "second, I'd prefer to pass the source and destination in this script rather then passing them later." but it looks like you're already doing that.  How or why is it not working?  What line in the code is not performing to your liking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`InputBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3yfdhzk5%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) function to prompt for user input. Rows can be removed from an Excel worksheet via `<range>.EntireRow.Delete`.

Something like this should do what you want:

```
xls = InputBox("Enter source file.")
csv = InputBox("Enter destination file.")

Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(xls)
oBook.Sheets(1).Range("1:4").EntireRow.Delete
oBook.SaveAs csv, 6
oBook.Close False
oExcel.Quit

WScript.Echo "Done"
```

**Edit:** If you want hardcoded paths, simply define them as strings:

```
xls = "C:\path\to\input.xls"
csv = "C:\path\to\output.csv"

Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(xls)
oBook.Sheets(1).Range("1:4").EntireRow.Delete
oBook.SaveAs csv, 6
oBook.Close False
oExcel.Quit

WScript.Echo "Done"
```

Comment: Thank you Ansgar that is kinda what i'm looking for. I'm going to be running this vbs code with SQL Server Agent and it has issues when passing parameters from vbs. I just want to hard code the source and the destination into the vbs rather then imputing it when the script runs.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ansgar Wiechers I was able to come up with this script

```
xls = "C:\[Path]"
csv = "c:\[Destination]"
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(xls)

oBook.Worksheets(2).Activate
oBook.Worksheets(2).Rows("1:4").Delete
oBook.SaveAs csv, 6
oBook.Close False
oExcel.Quit
```

And it runs like a champ in cmd. Thanks a million!

However, I went to implement this into my process and found out that SQL Server Agent has major issues in executing VBScripts.

cscript is the command that is suggested to execute the script, but it doesn't work. After more research I found that other people have had similar issues and they all suggest writing the script in VB.NET instead of VBScript. This way SSIS can process the script.

Ansgar I marked your response as the answer since it answered my question, but sadly it only lead me to a dead end with VBScript.